# Azure Blob - 503 Egress Is Over The Account Limit

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

So I'm getting this error occasionally:

> Error Initializing Stream Reader or Blob Not Found: Response status
> code does not indicate success: 503 (Egress is over the account
> limit.).

I'm not aware of an account limit and the file shouldn't have been large enough to break the throughput limits.  Blob storage has some amazingly high throughput limits.  Has anyone seen this and knows whats going on?  Is this just a new way to tell me that the blob isn't found with other misleading info?
Using WindowsAzure.Storage v9.3.3

Comment: haha, im impressed if you actually hit the limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account

Comment: Could you please tell us what your storage account type is? For example, `v1`, `v2`, you can refer to the official documents to compare whether your throughput exceeds the account limit. In addition, could you please show us your code? And what is the size of your file?

Comment: GenPurpose V2 account