# Egress is over the account limit when installing terraform provider

Tags: azure, github, terraform

I was trying to perform a `terraform init` and I came across the following issue

```
Error while installing mongodb/mongodbatlas v1.1.1 unsuccessful request to
https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-provider-mongodbatlas/releases/download/v1.1.1/terraform-provider-mongodbatlas_1.1.1_linux_amd64.zip
503 Egress is over the account limit
```

I see some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135070/azure-blob-503-egress-is-over-the-account-limit) [errors](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/115) related to Azure blob storage, but what does this have to do with me running `terraform` on a gcp machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've just started seeing this more frequently from GitHub over the last few hours (also pulling a different terraform provider). It looks like throttling from GitHub's Azure account - I assume they are experiencing a high number of downloads currently for some reason.

There is a feedback thread to GitHub here with some speculation about it being related to the recent AWS outage in us-east-1: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/8535